# navigator.connection does not return value in HTML5

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I am having issues getting values using the navigator.connection within javascript functions. I have two functions I am tryin to return data for, and both throw errors saying System.SystemException.

```
//Connection Type
    function getConnectionType() {
        //var connectionType = navigator.connection;
        var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
        var connectionType = connection.type

        window.external.notify("COT" + connectionType.toString());
    }

//Bandwidth
function getBandwidth() {
        //var online = navigator.onLine;
        var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
        var bandwidth = connection.bandwidth

        //window.external.notify("BAN" + bandwidth.toString() + " Mbps");
        window.external.notify("BAN" + bandwidth.toFixed(2) + " Mbps");
    }
```

I am calling this functions using InvokeScript in C#

```
private void RunPerformanceTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Bandwidth
        object bandwidth = Browser.InvokeScript("getBandwidth"); //Error

        //Connection Type
        object connectionType = Browser.InvokeScript("getConnectionType"); //Error
    }

private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = null;
        string statistic = null;

        statistic = e.Value.Substring(0, 3);
        value = e.Value.Substring(3);     

        switch (statistic)
        {
            //Bandwidth
            case "BAN":
                BANResultTextBlock.Text = value;
                break;
            //Connection type
            case "COT":
                COTResultTextBlock.Text = value;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

Error

> System.SystemException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233087   Message=An unknown error has occurred. Error:
>   80020101.   Source=Microsoft.Phone.Interop   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String
>   scriptName, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName)
>          at Network_Performance_Test.MainPage.RunPerformanceTestButton_Click(Object
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
>          at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex,
>   String eventName)   InnerException:

I believe the problem is with `navigation.connection`. I use this same implementation to return `window.performance.timing` data and it works perfectly. Any ideas? I really need this data for performance and enhancement purposes. To note, this is all done in the WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing http://www.sitepoint.com/use-network-information-api-improve-responsive-websites/ states that `At the time of writing, the Network Information API has little browser support and could change.`

Comment: It has been 4 years since this question was asked and yet this is not available on firefox  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation